# facebook cross domain receiver error

Tags: facebook

I am working on a facebook app when i try to invoke js for asking extended permission from the user i got the following error

> The Facebook Connect cross-domain
>   receiver URL
>   (http://[mydomain/folder]/gripsoft/xd_receiver.htm)
>   must have the application's Connect
>   URL (http://localhost:63919/) as a
>   prefix. You can configure the Connect
>   URL in the Application Settings
>   Editor.

Now the strange thing is that i have not specified **localhost:63919** anywhere in my application settings.
Can somebody tells me which link i am missing in this whole scenario.
(Enviornment IFrame based APP using Facebook Toolkit for .NET)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue unfortunately i was using wrong Api Key and thats why it was keep referring to my other test application. Just updating that if someone else encounter the issue , you have to check both Web.Config and Master Page/Web Form where you are invoking FaceBook.Connect to make sure Api Key matches with your application key.